# Why did iZombie add gourmet cooking shots in the second season?

Tags: cinematography, izombie

iZombie's main conceit is that the main character, Liv, accesses the memory and personality of murder victims by eating their brains. In the first season, this happened, but wasn't emphasized. In the second season, they show her making whatever dish she's eating the brains in with trendy, Youtube-style cooking close-ups with saturated color and unusual angles.

What is the purpose of these shots?

Comment: Because they're awesome? Why not? They're one of my favorite parts of the show.

Comment: I love them too! I was just wondering cause it's such a fast-paced show, with so much plot and so much humor. In most shows, I would think that those sequences were there to pad out the runtime, but iZombie has too much awesome for that explanation.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's at least one episode where they skipped it this season... within the last five episodes, so it may be a bit of that, too... but I have a feeling it's mostly for fun. :D

Comment: Liz used to be the cooking type before being turned. I think its thematic with her personality change.

Comment: Also, as far as padding goes, 5 seconds isn't really padding. And this may have something to do with the comic iZombie is based off.

Answer (score 3):

It puts an emphasis on the brain's importance but also how sometimes they are just left lying around and treated as normal food. This puts us the audience on edge whenever we see food that is Liv's so we realise something is happening or about to happen. Her eating Lowe's leftovers leads to her figuring out Blaine is murdering, it is also the reason Glida breaks back in after turning.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is used to emphasize the method of cooking. 
I have noticed in season 4, that each meal reflects the personnality of the victim. Episode one, the victim is a football fan, Liv makes "chicken wings". 
Episode two, the victim is a high class older lady that enjoys her drinks, Liv makes a cocktail. Episode three and four, the victim is a hopeless romantic that enjoys cooking, Liv makes heart shaped chocolates. Episode five, the victim is a canadian hockey player, Liv makes a poutine. 
I hadn't noticed the corrolation in the prior seasons. But this adds to the overall effect of the setup.

Also be noted that in the first season, Ravi wasn't aware of Liv's condition until further along in the season, meaning she would have to hide to consume her meals, whereas as the seasons progress, there is less need for her to hide and she can take time to fancy up her meals.